# Installed packages not recognized by conda

Tags: python, linux, conda

I have a conda environment (called p36), which when activated, has suddenly lost the ability to recognize installed packages/modules. For instance, with the conda env active:

```
 conda list -n p36
# packages in environment at /home/spadavec/miniconda3/envs/p36:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
absl-py                   0.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
...
...
keras                     2.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
```

It would appear `keras` is installed. However, if I try to import it, keras no longer seems to exist:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Interestingly, all of my python versions seem to be in alignment:

```
(p36) spadavec@turing:~/itx/collab/MGH/scripts$ python --version
Python 3.7.4
(p36) spadavec@turing:~/itx/collab/MGH/scripts$ which python
/home/spadavec/miniconda3/bin/python
```

Any idea as to how to fix this? PYTHONPATH isn't set in this case, and my PATH calls the miniconda3 env first.

Comment: shouldn't  `which python` be pointing to /.../envs/p36/bin/python? did you forget to activate the environment

Comment: I just realized that my "python 2.6" env also points to the same python path (e.g. python 3.7). I thought that the path was correct, but will investigate

Comment: I tried reinstalling `keras` via conda, and the package manager mentioned that my installation/env was out of alignment. After re-installing keras alone, all of my packages were recognized again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reinstalling keras via conda, and the package manager mentioned that my installation/env was out of alignment. After re-installing keras alone, all of my packages were recognized again.